# Any idiom for someone who tends to do things in too much of a hurry?

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

"Were you born at six months?" is a kind of expression we use in Persian about someone who's not patient enough and **tends to do things in too much of a hurry**!

Is there anything like that in English? Any similar expressions?

Comment: *He's pressed for time.*

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - nice expression, but it doesn’t refer to specific  trait of a person character.

Comment: @Hachi, That's why it's a 'comment'. 

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - yes, I can’t think of a proper idiom. I wonder if there is one.

Comment: Can't think of any expression but *hasty* is the word you need. @ML2020

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - Can we say "You're a sort of guy who goes off half cocked"?

Comment: @ML2020, [Yes, you can](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/go-off-half-cocked).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - And in case you're a native speaker, do you know if it sounds old-fashioned or something?

Comment: A person who really wants to get on with doing something is said to be **straining at the leash**. Someone not taking enough time over a job is _over-hasty_.

Comment: There's always someone who is "chomping at the bit" or "champing at the bit". https://grammarist.com/usage/champing-chomping-at-the-bit/ This is pretty close, but it can have positive, as well as negative, connotations.

Comment: ***go off half-cocked*** has a different connotation: *to express unguarded emotion; to lose one’s temper.* https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/fm3etti

Comment: I would point out that "Haste makes waste" is an old idiom.

Answer (score 1):

He's a person for whom

> There's never enough time to do it right, but there's always enough time to do it over.
>   - attributed to Jack Bergman at [Quoteland](http://www.quoteland.com/author/Jack-Bergman-Quotes/3079/), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/quotes/comments/dgvpaw/theres_never_enough_time_to_do_it_right_but/) and [elsewhere](https://inpdcenter.com/blog/time-right-time-over/)

The idea is that they are in such a hurry that they don't get it right, and therefore need to take time to do it again. The implication is that they would have completed the task more quickly if they had taken the time to do it properly the first time.

Comment: " There is never enough time to do it right the first time but there is always enough time to do it over . ”  [1968](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Graphic_Science/LdwjAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22time+to+do+it+right%22&dq=%22time+to+do+it+right%22&printsec=frontcover).  If the Jack Bergman referenced is supposed to be the congressman born in 1947 and who received his undergraduate degree in 1969, it's unlikely he originated this expression.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an idom for someone like this but they can be described as **hasty**. Merriam Webster defines [hasty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hasty#synonyms) in reference to actions as "fast and typically superficial" using the example "made a hasty examination of the wound" but the word has been applied to people, particularly in reference to decisions.

An example of this is the spoken epilogue of the comic song [Right Said Fred](https://genius.com/Bernard-cribbins-right-said-fred-lyrics) which follows the tale of three removal men trying to move a large, heavy, unspecified piece of furniture from an upstairs room and failing. After the leading man, Fred, has tried all sorts of strategies and ended up killed or seriously injured by falling rubble while trying to make a hole for the item to drop through, the other two go off and one of them, the narrator, says "You see the trouble with Fred is, he's too **hasty**. You'll never get nowhere if you're too **hasty**"

The use of "hasty" in the song is ironic but indicates that **hasty** was idiomatic in the early 1960s when the song was written by Ted Dicks and Myles Rudge and recorded by Bernard Cribbens. It's probably less common now but is still recognisable.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hasty&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chasty%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

"Rome was not built in a day." Is often used as a warning or admonishment about a plan that is/was too hasty.  While not necessarily directed at a person, it can be used that way.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Like] a bull at a gate**
>
> If you tackle a job very quickly, without any real thought about what
>   you are doing, you are going at it *like a bull at a gate*.

[[UsingEnglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/like+a+bull+at+a+gate.html)]

> **like a bull at a gate**
>
> Very quickly and rashly; hastily, without careful thinking or
>   planning.
>
> - I only have a few hours before this essay is due, so I'm going at it like a bull at a gate.
> - With only a few seconds left in the match, he started charging at his opponent like a bull at a gate out of desperation.

[[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bull+at+a+gate)]

The metaphor can be used to describe the associated character trait:

> - He is like a bull at a gate. He never takes the logical route. He always takes a sledgehammer to crack a nut ....

[[The Boy with the 40 Year Old Brain_ By Ken Coleman](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HSZBjEVpyKIC&pg=PA410&lpg=PA410&dq=%22he+is+like+a+Bull+at+a+gate%22&source=bl&ots=spyQicoA5u&sig=ACfU3U1L559hxsbYdBS4AK2gtqbKiTAgIw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22he%20is%20like%20a%20Bull%20at%20a%20gate%22&f=false)

Comment: Yes, but the OP is looking for an idiomatic expression to refer to a characteristic trait of someone who would  always or in most cases do anything   too quickly.

Comment: Yes; I've added an example showing the broader usage I'm familiar with. It was actually 'He's a bull at a gate', a metaphor even by the standards of the similes-are-not-metaphors brigade.